# Find the smallest sigma-algebra.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

[image]

My attempt at finding the smallest sigma-algebra:

$$
\sigma(A) = \{\varnothing, \Omega, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{2,3,4,5\}, \{1,3,4,5\}, \{1,2,4,5\}, \{4,5\}.
$$

Is this correct? What am I missing? And any idea how to solve $P(\{4,5\})$ or $P(\{4\})$ as given in the question? Thank you.

Comment: You need it to be closed under unions, but you don't have {1,2}, for example, or the complement of {4,5} either. Think about why or why not this isn't just the power set.

Comment: Is this not just closure under complements $\varnothing \in \sigma(A)$ and so $\varnothing^c = \Omega \in \sigma(A)$ @sudeep5221?

Comment: Also it's best to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your questions.

Comment: A finite sigma-algebra must have $2^n$ events in it for some positive integer $n$, including $\nullset$ and $\Omega$. Your result has $9$ sets in it, and so is obviously incorrect.

Comment: @DilipSarwate should the sigma-algebra have 2^5 = 32 events since Ω has 5 elements? I have been able to find 16. But that's 2^4.

Comment: @AndreyYanyuk  should the sigma-algebra have 2^5 = 32 events since Ω has 5 elements? I have been able to find 16. But that's 2^4.

Comment: If you have $\Omega$ a finite set, the power set $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is the largest possible $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ which contains $2^{|\Omega|}$ elements. You aren't looking for that largest $\sigma$-algebra. There's also a smallest sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}_{min} = \{\varnothing, \Omega\}$ and always the case that any other $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ satisfies $\mathcal{F}_{min} \subseteq \mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. So in short no it should not have the maximum amount of elements a $\sigma$-algebra defined on $\Omega$ could have.

Comment: No, there shouldn't be $2^5$ events in the _smallest_ $\sigma$-algebra in which $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}$ are given to be events.  $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4,5\}$ is a _partition_ of $\Omega$ into _four_ disjoint events, and the _smallest_ $\sigma$-algera that contains $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}$  as events is the power set of this partition, which has $2^4$ events in it as you have found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\scrM}{\mathscr{M}}$
You can do this systematically by considering the requirements in the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra.

> **Definition:** Given a set $\Omega$ a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ denoted $\scrM$ is a sigma-algebra in $\Omega$ if $\varnothing \in \scrM$, the collection $\scrM$ is closed under countable unions, and $\scrM$ is closed under complements.

So now if you take $S = \{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\} \}$, you can ask yourself how can this be enlarged so that it is in fact a $\sigma$-algebra. Of course as you've correctly done we must also have $\varnothing$ in the collection if it is to be a $\sigma$-algebra. Taking unions certainly gives you elements like $\{1\} \cup \{2\} = \{1,2\}$, and so you know immediately that you need to enlarge $S$ to some
$$
S' = \{\varnothing, \{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{3\}\}.
$$
More than this you also need closure under complements, so this tells you that sets like $\{1\}^c = \{2,3,4,5\}$ must also be elements of the $\sigma$-algebra.

But importantly note that once we know $\{1,2\}$ must be an element of the $\sigma$-algebra it follows that $\{1,2\}^c = \{3,4,5\}$ must also be in the $\sigma$-algebra due to closure under complements, so you've missed those sets.

For $p(\{4,5\}$ and $p(\{4\})$ a useful thing to remember is that for probability measures $p(\Omega) = 1$, and if $E$ is any measurable set $E$ and $E^c$ are definitely disjoint so that $$p(E^c)+p(E) =p(E^c \cup E) = p(\Omega) = 1.$$

Comment: Thank you. But if the probability measure P corresponds to the probability space (Ω, , P), then isn't P({4}) not definable because {4} is not in  (i.e., because it's not in the sigma algebra, it's not "measurable")? So can ({4,5}) or ({4}) even be defined? Is it possible to even calculate them?

Comment: Well it's true that $\{4,5\}$ is not an element of $\mathcal{A}$, but is it true that it's not in the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$? Note that from closure under complements and countable unions you can prove to yourself a $\sigma$-algebra is also closed under finite intersections. Consider $(A \cup B)^c$.

Comment: But you have the right idea for $\{4\}$.

Comment: It might help to list the minimal $\sigma$-algebra containing $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$ explicitly and then try some combinations. It's not terribly difficult.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what independent means. Are {1} and {1,3} considered to be independent? Or does the common 1 in them make them non-independent?

Comment: Ah, that's a good place to start. Two events $A,B \in \mathscr{M}$ are independent if $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)).